# Regex to extract number from between parentheses, modify, then replace original number

Tags: regex

Trying to extract the digits between the parentheses (AA) and modify (e.g. multiply by 300) and  update  the old value (AA) using the new value which is (AA*300) in the whole text.

Example input:

```
RRRR  TTTTYYY (22);
UUUUUUU IIIIII4 (55);
```

Expected output:

```
RRRR TTTTYYY (6600);
UUUUUUU IIIIII4 (16500);
```

Comment: Please show any attempts you have made.

Comment: Do you only expect there to be a single level of parentheses? (e.g. no nested parentheses)

Comment: Could you edit and elaborate on your question a bit? I don't understand at all what you're asking. You're using abbreviated words, making it seem like you didn't put much effort into this.

Answer (score 0):

`gawk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '{print $1,$2,"("300*gensub(/\((.*)\);/,"\\1",1,$3)");"}' file   

RRRR TTTTYYY (6600);
UUUUUUU IIIIII4 (16500);
```

condition based on the value in parenthesis

```
$ awk '{v=gensub(/\((.*)\);/,"\\1",1,$NF); if(int(v)==v) $NF="("(300*v)");"}1' file

RRRR TTTTYYY (6600);
UUUUUUU IIIIII4 (16500);
ZZZ FFF (2,3);
```

where I added the last line to the input file.

Perhaps this is a better solution with restricting match on integers only

```
$ awk '{if(match($NF,/\([0-9]+\)/)) 
            $NF="(" 300*substr($NF,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2) ");"}1' file

RRRR TTTTYYY (6600);
UUUUUUU IIIIII4 (16500);
ZZZ FFF (2,3);
```

Comment: Works fine.

Is there any generic solution :
test if the number between between the parentheses (AA)   is an interger, then *300 ,  any where in the text ,
avoid (2,3) type of numbers.

Comment: for integer test, you can do `int(x)==x`

Answer (score 0):

in Perl, procedurally:

```
my $str = 'RRRR  TTTTYYY (22)';
my $num = $1 if $str =~ /\((\d+)\)/;
my $result = $num * 300;
$str =~ s/$num/$res/; 
print $str;
```

functionally:

```
sub x {
    my $str = @_;
    my $num = $1 if $str =~ /\((\d+)\)/;
    my $result = $num * 300;
    $str =~ s/$num/$res/; 
    return $str;
}

print x('RRRR  TTTTYYY (22)');
```

as a one-liner where `file.txt` contains one string per line

```
perl -lne '$num = $1 if $_ =~ /\((\d+)\)/; $res = $num * 300; $_ =~ s/$num/$res/; print' file.txt
```

Comment: Please check the folowing picture  you can get an idea 
thank you for your help 
https://s32.postimg.org/lena34479/image.png

Comment: my third example should do exactly that. paste it into your command line and change 'file.txt' to the path to your file. if you're in windows you might have to change the `'` to `"`

Comment: note that the regex `/\((\d+)\)/` can only capture an int. any character not 0 - 9 (like `,`) will cause the match to fail and in turn the substitution would not be made

Comment: Did you test this in a case where there are two sets of parentheses in a line?

Comment: no because I don't think that was in the use case. this would not work for multiple sets of parenthesis

Comment: I like your use of `/e` in your answer although it's probably a little harder for OP to understand

Answer (score 0):

If the only digits in your string are the ones inside the parentheses, then this is pretty simple in Perl:

```
$ perl -pE 's/(\d+?)/300*$1/eg' your_input_file.txt
RRR  TTTTYYY (6600);
UUUUUUU IIIIII1200 (16500);
```

If you need to check for the parentheses, then it gets a little harder

```
$ perl -pE 's/(?<=\()(\d+?)(?=\))/300*$1/eg' your_input_file.txt
RRR  TTTTYYY (6600);
UUUUUUU IIIIII4 (16500);
```